# How to check for more then one equal records together at the same ExecuteScalar() command

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database, datagridview

im having a problam for checking 2 records together at the same ExecuteScalar command .

i want to search together 2 records in the same row in a different column in my local DB , im trying to do like in my code below but only if im doing it on 1 condition its ok , but i want on 2 conditions at the same time , in the same row.

this is my code , when im in a loop that checks every time each row from my DataGridView if its equal to my local DB :

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {

            string constring = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\john\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Project\Project\DB.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
            {

                  using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) from ResultsTable where TagNumber=@TagNumber AND Date=@Date", con))

                {
                    con.Open();

                    string smdt1 = row.Cells["Exposure Date"].Value.ToString();
                    string format1 = "dd.MM.yyyy";
                    DateTime dt1 = DateTime.ParseExact(smdt1, format1, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);


                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", dt1);

                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TagNumber", row.Cells["Device #"].Value);


                    int userCount = (int)sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();

                    if (userCount > 0)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("found!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("not found!");
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

the date cast is just for im getting a date like 23.05.2015 and i wanted to cast it to date type for the data base like 23/05/2015 . 
i just want to check duplicate for 2 records in the same row

(its 2 primary keys in the same table) 
before im inserting them .

Answer (score 0):

after sqlcommand add this

```
IDataReader reader = cm.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    if (reader.GetValue(0) != 0)
        // your Code
}
```

Comment: how can i know if this is checking both records in the same row??